# Reopen question about Obama vs Trump immigration bans

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

I asked [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36956/did-president-obama-institute-immigration-restrictions-in-2011-that-were-similar) and it was closed as a dupe of [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36950/did-the-obama-administration-halt-processing-of-iraqi-refugees-back-in-2011).

I think these questions are not duplicates because one asks if Obama took immigration actions in 2011, and the other asks are the immigration actions Obama took in 2011 the same as what Trump did today. The key difference here is that my question presupposes that Obama took immigration actions in 2011, where as the other question does not.

Moreover, my question currently does not have a satisfactory answer (even though there is one with a lot of upvotes).For this reason I believe my question should be re-opened

Answer (score 4):

I'm not strongly opposed to reopening (and if you get 4 more re-open votes, it will be done without me), but I am not excited by this question.

- It asks about "similarities", which is ultimately opinion-based, and doesn't belong here.
- You seem to be in possession of all of the facts. The examples you gave cite references. The existing answers cite references. What is left to answer?
- You have two highly upvoted answers (I can tell they made it to the Hot Network Question list, without even checking :-( ) but you want different ones, without any suggestion of what might be wrong with them. This question looks like it is already answered as well as it is going to be.
- It is one of a slew of recent questions that trouble me - that are getting hung up on the trees, rather than asking about the forest. Whether Obama did something similar seven years ago has no bearing on whether the recent Executive Order is "good"/"fair"/"effective" or not. It is just trying to work out whether the Republicans have a stick to hit the Democrats with.

Comment: I agree that the answers answer the question, but I don't think that having existing answers is a good reason to keep a question closed. I also agree that the premise seems flawed, but it's a fact that is being brought up, so it makes sense to check if the fact is even true.

Comment: @tim: It is a response to the final sentence of the meta-question, which argues that it should be reopened to because the OP is unhappy with the existing answers. I am dismissing that argument.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it should be reopened.